# LED video wall power supply

Tags: power-supply

I am working on an LED panel video wall project made up of 3x8 squares of 128x128 pixel panels. Each panel has a worst case power draw of 65 W (typical: 35 W). I can get the panels as either 24 V or 48 V supply voltage (an embedded DC to DC switcher will make 5 V for the LEDs).

I plan to put the 24 V or 48 V power supplies in a NEMA box at floor level and run power cables 10 ft up the wall (either inside the wall or in a raceway enclosure). Space constraints won't allow me to put the power supplies in or near the video wall.

I am leaning toward choosing the 48 V supply to reduce the current through the power cables, but I am confused by the NEC specifications for low-voltage systems in this case.  Some sections refer to less than 50 V, Article 411 Low-voltage lighting uses less than 30 V, Table 11 says Class 2 power supplies between 20 and 60 V. Does the low-voltage lighting section apply to this case? Would the 24 V panels be a safer route to meet NEC requirements?  Am I missing an obvious section in the NEC specifications that would apply to powering a video wall with 24 VDC or 48 VDC?

Also, in Table 11a on Class 2 power supplies, they set the maximum VA to 100 for 20-60 V supplies. Does that mean that I need to use 16 100 W power supplies? But then to have less than 100 W per power cable, I would need to run 24 separate cables to each panel since 2 panels combined could add up to over 100 W. Then I would need 24 100 W power supplies. This seems absurd to me, I must be misunderstanding the NEC spec.

I would prefer to use 6 300 W or 4 500 W supplies, then run 6 or 4 separate power cables up to the video wall and distribute the power to each panel. Is there something in the NEC spec that would allow this?

Answer (score 0):

Since your application demands up to 2kVA LVDC   this NEC class 2 of product is not desirable.  You want a LED driver that is UL60950-1 compliant and 48V is a wise choice since 50A cables are rather heavy gauge. Look harder for an opportunity to locate it close to the load.

Without more details I might suggest 48V LED strings with http://www.meanwell.com/productPdf.aspx?i=366  Does this work for you??
Have a hot spare for reliability or current sharing.